# Inconsistent scipiy.find_peaks results from pandas_udf with pyspark 3.0

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, scipy, user-defined-functions

I try to use scipy's find_peaks inside pyspark's pandas_udf. A barebone example:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext, Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, col
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType 

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from scipy.signal import find_peaks

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("yarn") \
.appName("UDF_debug") \
.config("spark.yarn.dist.archives", "hdfs://PATH/TO/MY/USERFOLDER/envs/my_env.zip#MYENV")\
.config("spark.submit.deployMode", "client")\
.config("spark.yarn.queue", "root.dev")\
.enableHiveSupport()\
.getOrCreate()

# Create a sample dataframe and a corresponding pandas data frame, for cross-checking
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [Row(id=1, c=3),
    Row(id=2,  c=6),
    Row(id=3,  c=2),
    Row(id=4,  c=9),
    Row(id=5,  c=7)])

dfp = df.toPandas()

def peak_finder(C: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
     # Find peaks (maxima)
    pos_peaks, pos_properties = find_peaks(C)
    
    # Create an empty series of appropriate length
    r = pd.Series(np.full(len(C), np.nan))

    # Wherever a peak was found ...
    for idx in pos_peaks:
        # ... mark it by noting its height
        r[idx] = C[idx]

    return r

# Peak finding using pyspark's pandas_udf
peak_finder_udf = pandas_udf(peak_finder, returnType=DoubleType())
df = df.withColumn('peak', peak_finder_udf(df.c))
df.show()


# Peak finding directly on a pandas df
dfp["peaks_pandas"] = peak_finder(dfp["c"])
print(dfp)
```

The result of the two prints is as follows. First, peak finding with pandas_udf:

```
+---+---+----+
| id|  c|peak|
+---+---+----+
|  1|  3|null|
|  2|  6|null|
|  3|  2|null|
|  4|  9| 9.0|
|  5|  7|null|
+---+---+----+
```

Second, using just stock pandas and numpy on the edge node:

```
   id  c  peaks_pandas
0   1  3           NaN
1   2  6           6.0
2   3  2           NaN
3   4  9           9.0
4   5  7           NaN
```

The line with id=2 is inconsistent.

This might be understandable from the [pyspark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html#series-to-series), stating:

> Internally, PySpark will execute a Pandas UDF by splitting columns
> into batches and calling the function for each batch as a subset of
> the data, then concatenating the results together.

It seems weird that such a small split should occur, but maybe ...

**Question 1: Is this inconsistent behaviour expected? Can I avoid it?**

**EDIT: Answer: Yes, this is due to partitioning. See my comment below.**

Another weird behaviour might point to the solution (but to me raises further questions). Continuing with the above code:

```
fname = "debug.parquet"
df.dropna().write.parquet(fname)
dfnew = spark.read.parquet(fname)
dfnew.show()
```

It yields the result

```
+---+---+----+
| id|  c|peak|
+---+---+----+
|  4|  9|null|
+---+---+----+
```

Peak is no longer = 9, as it should be, but null.

**Question 2: Can anyone explain this data loss during saving?**

Relevant packages in conda env:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main    defaults
arrow-cpp                 0.15.1           py38h7cd5009_5    defaults
attrs                     19.3.0                     py_0    defaults
backcall                  0.2.0                      py_0    defaults
blas                      1.0                         mkl    defaults
bleach                    3.1.5                      py_0    defaults
boost-cpp                 1.71.0               h7b6447c_0    defaults
brotli                    1.0.7                he6710b0_0    defaults
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py38h7b6447c_1000    defaults
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7b6447c_0    defaults
c-ares                    1.15.0            h7b6447c_1001    defaults
ca-certificates           2020.6.24                     0    defaults
certifi                   2020.6.20                py38_0    defaults
cffi                      1.14.0           py38he30daa8_1    defaults
chardet                   3.0.4                 py38_1003    defaults
cryptography              2.9.2            py38h1ba5d50_0    defaults
dbus                      1.13.16              hb2f20db_0    defaults
decorator                 4.4.2                      py_0    defaults
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0    defaults
double-conversion         3.1.5                he6710b0_1    defaults
entrypoints               0.3                      py38_0    defaults
expat                     2.2.9                he6710b0_2    defaults
fontconfig                2.13.0               h9420a91_0    defaults
freetype                  2.10.2               h5ab3b9f_0    defaults
gflags                    2.2.2                he6710b0_0    defaults
glib                      2.65.0               h3eb4bd4_0    defaults
glog                      0.4.0                he6710b0_0    defaults
grpc-cpp                  1.26.0               hf8bcb03_0    defaults
gst-plugins-base          1.14.0               hbbd80ab_1    defaults
gstreamer                 1.14.0               hb31296c_0    defaults
icu                       58.2                 he6710b0_3    defaults
idna                      2.10                       py_0    defaults
importlib-metadata        1.7.0                    py38_0    defaults
importlib_metadata        1.7.0                         0    defaults
intel-openmp              2020.1                      217    defaults
ipykernel                 5.3.0            py38h5ca1d4c_0    defaults
ipython                   7.16.1           py38h5ca1d4c_0    defaults
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py38_0    defaults
ipywidgets                7.5.1                      py_0    defaults
jedi                      0.17.1                   py38_0    defaults
jinja2                    2.11.2                     py_0    defaults
jpeg                      9b                   h024ee3a_2    defaults
json5                     0.9.5                      py_0    defaults
jsonschema                3.2.0                    py38_0    defaults
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py38_7    defaults
jupyter_client            6.1.3                      py_0    defaults
jupyter_console           6.1.0                      py_0    defaults
jupyter_core              4.6.3                    py38_0    defaults
jupyterlab                2.1.5                      py_0    defaults
jupyterlab_server         1.1.5                      py_0    defaults
ld_impl_linux-64          2.33.1               h53a641e_7    defaults
libboost                  1.71.0               h97c9712_0    defaults
libedit                   3.1.20191231         h7b6447c_0    defaults
libevent                  2.1.8                h1ba5d50_0    defaults
libffi                    3.3                  he6710b0_2    defaults
libgcc-ng                 9.1.0                hdf63c60_0    defaults
libgfortran-ng            7.3.0                hdf63c60_0    defaults
libpng                    1.6.37               hbc83047_0    defaults
libprotobuf               3.11.4               hd408876_0    defaults
libsodium                 1.0.18               h7b6447c_0    defaults
libstdcxx-ng              9.1.0                hdf63c60_0    defaults
libuuid                   1.0.3                h1bed415_2    defaults
libxcb                    1.14                 h7b6447c_0    defaults
libxml2                   2.9.10               he19cac6_1    defaults
lz4-c                     1.8.1.2              h14c3975_0    defaults
markupsafe                1.1.1            py38h7b6447c_0    defaults
mistune                   0.8.4           py38h7b6447c_1000    defaults
mkl                       2020.1                      217    defaults
mkl-service               2.3.0            py38he904b0f_0    defaults
mkl_fft                   1.1.0            py38h23d657b_0    defaults
mkl_random                1.1.1            py38h0573a6f_0    defaults
nbconvert                 5.6.1                    py38_0    defaults
nbformat                  5.0.7                      py_0    defaults
ncurses                   6.2                  he6710b0_1    defaults
notebook                  6.0.3                    py38_0    defaults
numpy                     1.18.5           py38ha1c710e_0    defaults
numpy-base                1.18.5           py38hde5b4d6_0    defaults
openssl                   1.1.1g               h7b6447c_0    defaults
packaging                 20.4                       py_0    defaults
pandas                    1.0.5            py38h0573a6f_0    defaults
pandoc                    2.9.2.1                       0    defaults
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py38_1    defaults
parso                     0.7.0                      py_0    defaults
pcre                      8.44                 he6710b0_0    defaults
pexpect                   4.8.0                    py38_0    defaults
pickleshare               0.7.5                 py38_1000    defaults
pip                       20.1.1                   py38_1    defaults
prometheus_client         0.8.0                      py_0    defaults
prompt-toolkit            3.0.5                      py_0    defaults
prompt_toolkit            3.0.5                         0    defaults
ptyprocess                0.6.0                    py38_0    defaults
py4j                      0.10.9                     py_0    defaults
pyarrow                   0.15.1           py38h0573a6f_0    defaults
pycparser                 2.20                       py_0    defaults
pygments                  2.6.1                      py_0    defaults
pyopenssl                 19.1.0                   py38_0    defaults
pyparsing                 2.4.7                      py_0    defaults
pyqt                      5.9.2            py38h05f1152_4    defaults
pyrsistent                0.16.0           py38h7b6447c_0    defaults
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py38_0    defaults
pyspark                   3.0.0                      py_0    defaults
python                    3.8.3                hcff3b4d_2    defaults
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0    defaults
pytz                      2020.1                     py_0    defaults
pyzmq                     19.0.1           py38he6710b0_1    defaults
qt                        5.9.7                h5867ecd_1    defaults
qtconsole                 4.7.5                      py_0    defaults
qtpy                      1.9.0                      py_0    defaults
re2                       2019.08.01           he6710b0_0    defaults
readline                  8.0                  h7b6447c_0    defaults
requests                  2.24.0                     py_0    defaults
scipy                     1.5.0            py38h0b6359f_0    defaults
send2trash                1.5.0                    py38_0    defaults
setuptools                47.3.1                   py38_0    defaults
sip                       4.19.13          py38he6710b0_0    defaults
six                       1.15.0                     py_0    defaults
snappy                    1.1.8                he6710b0_0    defaults
sqlite                    3.32.3               h62c20be_0    defaults
terminado                 0.8.3                    py38_0    defaults
testpath                  0.4.4                      py_0    defaults
thrift-cpp                0.11.0               h02b749d_3    defaults
tk                        8.6.10               hbc83047_0    defaults
tornado                   6.0.4            py38h7b6447c_1    defaults
traitlets                 4.3.3                    py38_0    defaults
uriparser                 0.9.3                he6710b0_1    defaults
urllib3                   1.25.9                     py_0    defaults
wcwidth                   0.2.5                      py_0    defaults
webencodings              0.5.1                    py38_1    defaults
wheel                     0.34.2                   py38_0    defaults
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                    py38_0    defaults
xz                        5.2.5                h7b6447c_0    defaults
zeromq                    4.3.2                he6710b0_2    defaults
zipp                      3.1.0                      py_0    defaults
zlib                      1.2.11               h7b6447c_3    defaults
zstd                      1.3.7                h0b5b093_0    defaults
```

I also tried with pyspark 2.4.5 (combined with pyarrow 0.8). Exact same results.

Comment: Question 1 is answered: I just found out that it is indeed the partitioning that causes this behaviour. I did it by just assigning a random number in the peak_finder function.

Comment: Found a sort of workaround for question 2: Converting first do rdd and then immediately back to data frame solved the issue (i.e. adding .rdd.toDF()).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1: Inconsistent behaviour is indeed due to partitioning.

Question 2: Workaround found: Converting first to rdd and then immediately back to data frame solved the issue (i.e. adding .rdd.toDF()). I am unclear about the reason, probably something going on in the background that I don't understand.